# Checking if a python iterable is empty without relying on `len` or consuming the iterator

Tags: python

I've written the following code to reverse the edges of a graph, expressed as an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) `Mapping`.

```py
from typing import Mapping, Any, Sized
from collections import defaultdict

def edge_reversed_graph(g: Mapping[Any, Sized]):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for src, dst_nodes in g.items():
        if len(dst_nodes):
            for dst in dst_nodes:
                d[dst].add(src)
        elif src not in d:
            d[src] = set()
    return d
```

Example:

```py
>>> graph = dict(a='c', b='cd', c='abd', e='')
>>> assert edge_reversed_graph(graph) == {'c': {'a', 'b'}, 'd': {'c', 'b'}, 'a': {'c'}, 'b': {'c'}, 'e': set()}
```

I'd like to be able to just require the graph to be `Mapping[Any, Iterable]`, that is the adjacency "list" not to necessarily have to have a length. This is achievable using a flag variable, but I'm looking for a more elegant and efficient solution, otherwise making the function work with a larger group of objects wouldn't be worth it to me.

Comment: I think a flag variable is by far the simplest and most efficient solution; there are many other ways to do it probably, but that would be bending over backwards a lot. You can't get the length of an iterator, so you would have to at least partially consume the iterable and then do something with that, which is all a lot more complex than setting a flag.

Comment: It appears that the code is not correct to begin with. The ``else`` clause can erase incoming edges to a node without outgoing edges, and fails to include nodes with only outgoing edges. Compare ``edge_reversed_graph(dict(e='', a='e'))`` and ``edge_reversed_graph(dict(a='e', e=''))``. In short, neither the ``if`` nor the ``else`` clause should exist – whether to write them with ``len`` or otherwise does not change that.

Comment: No. That solution would consume the iterable. There is a solution that is to do something like `first_element = next(dst_nodes, sentinel)`, check for `sentinel` (indicating the `dst_nodes` was empty), and if not, iterate over `dst_nodes` where we "added the `first_element` back on. But that still seems to convoluted to be worth it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I think you're right, I'll recheck the code.

Comment: @thorwhalen `next(..., sentinel)` would be exactly one of those bend-over-backwards solutions I alluded to. But as you said yourself, that's a lot more complex and inefficient than a flag.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, indeed there was a mistake in my code. I corrected it now.

Comment: @thorwhalen The currenct code still fails to insert the node ``a`` in e.g. ``edge_reversed_graph(dict(e='', a='e'))``. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking whether the container/iterable of outgoing edges is empty is a red herring: Each node must always be ensured to exist.

- If there are ingoing edges, it might have been added before. *The node may not be overwritten even if it has no outgoing edges.*
- If there are outgoing but no ingoing edges, it must still be added. *The node must exist regardless of ingoing edges.*

This removes the need to check whether there are outgoing edges: Always add the `src` node *if it does not exist*. Always iterate all outgoing edges, of which there might be none.

```py
from typing import Mapping, TypeVar, Iterable, Set
from collections import defaultdict

T = TypeVar('T')

def edge_reversed_graph(g: Mapping[T, Iterable[T]]) -> Mapping[T, Set[T]]:
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for src, dst_nodes in g.items():
        d.setdefault(src, set())  # add node if not present
        for dst in dst_nodes:     # empty iterable does nothing
            d[dst].add(src)
    return d
```

Comment: clear winner! And extra points for the `T = TypeVar('T')`!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what I assume you mean with flag (having a `bool` variable set to `True` inside the loop), but more efficient:

```
def edge_reversed_graph(g: Mapping[Any, Iterable]):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    none = object()
    for src, dst_nodes in g.items():
        dst = none
        for dst in dst_nodes:
            d[dst].add(src)
        if dst is none:
            d[src] = set()
    return d
```

Comment: @deceze It's more efficient than the assumed extra `nonempty = True` inside the loop. And `None` could be in the destinations, so that's not safe.

Comment: `assert edge_reversed_graph(dict(a='e', e='')) == {'e': {'a'}, 'a': set()}` fails.

Comment: @thorwhalen Well if that's a failure then so does your original code fail. I didn't change the logic.

Comment: Indeed, @MisterMiyagi pointed this mistake and I've corrected it. Sorry about that.